# Declaring textView gives NullPointerException on textView

Tags: android, listview, textview

I try to change the textView color when the rating from "nearby places api" is less or equal than 3 to red and more than 3 to green, but i get a NullPointerException like below:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setTextColor(int)' on a null object reference
```

Here are part of my code, i know that declaring the textView is not in the right place. But, i tried to declare it in onCreate and out of it but i get the same error.

Part of the activity:

```
@Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.list_view_activity);
    myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.placesList);
}

public class readFromGooglePlaceAPI extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

  @Override protected String doInBackground(String... param) {
    return readJSON(param[0]);
}

protected void onPostExecute(String str) {
    myArrayList = new ArrayList<GetterSetter>();

    String rating=" -NA-";
    try {

        JSONObject root = new JSONObject(str);
        JSONArray results = root.getJSONArray("results");

        for (int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++) {

            addValues = new GetterSetter();
            TextView rate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rating);

            JSONObject arrayItems = results.getJSONObject(i);
            if(!arrayItems.isNull("rating")){
                rating = arrayItems.getString("rating");

                if(Float.parseFloat(rating) <= 3){
                    rate.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                }
                else if(Float.parseFloat(rating) > 3){
                    rate.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                }
            }

            addValues.setRating(rating);
            myArrayList.add(addValues);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error", "Exception ..." , e);
    }
    adapter = new CustomAdapter(ListActivity.this, R.layout.list_row, myArrayList);
    myList.setAdapter(adapter);

}

}
```

list_view_activity.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/placesList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:paddingTop="70dp"
    android:divider="@drawable/divider"
    android:dividerHeight="1px"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/listview_selector">
</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

list_row.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="20dp"
android:paddingRight="20dp" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ratingRext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/name"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:text="Rating :"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textColor="#282f8d" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rating"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/ratingRext"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:textSize="12sp" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The `TextView rate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rating);` must change to something like `TextView rate = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.rating);`. However, you have no access to your list_row's view object at this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your code post you are taking the handle of `TextView` from activity. But there is no `TextView` in your activity file. Its is in your layout used for custom adapter. So you need to handle the things in the adapter class.

In the `getView()` method of the adapter based on the model list value in your case it is `myArrayList`. 
Maintain a attribute in this pojo class with respect to ratings and in the getview you will have the handle of test view as well as this model class and you can perform your task over there.